# please enable billing in your cloud project

Tags: android, gradle

при запуске gradle получаю такое сообщение:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden { "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "location" : "Authorization", "locationType" : "header", "message" : "The account for the specified project has been disabled.", "reason" : "accountDisabled" } ], "message" : "The account for the specified project has been disabled." }
```

просьба помочь разобраться, что оно от меня хочет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это заголовок ошибки, только что разобрался в чем дело. Я пробовал подключить вчера онлайн тестирование, но что-то пошло не так. И успешно забыл об этом. А сейчас вот оно начало требовать подключить эту штуку и я без малейшего понятия, что оно от меня хочет так как я же никаких покупок не делал в моем приложении. В итоге удалил эту настройку и все стало норм.

Comment: пожалуйста не забудьте пометить ответ как принятый

Comment: смогу только через два дня